# Problem saving Text file in database using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, mysql, hibernate

I'm having a problem saving large text files to MySQL database. If the text file size is around 5KB it successfully saves.  If file is 148KB then I get this error from Hibernate:

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

These is the SQL shows by Hibernate:

```
Hibernate: insert into file_table (ID,FILE) values (?, ?)
```

And in my hibernate file I'm using java.sql.Blob to store the file.

Anyone knows why it fails to save a file size of 148KB but if I open that same file, cut it down to around 5KB, it will successfully save it?

I thought the default limit was I think 2GB?  This is weird.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation of the maximum length for different string columns in mysql:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-type-overview.html

A standard TEXT column only allows 65,535 characters max, you probably want a LONGTEXT column which allows around 4Gb per column.

Comment: Thank you. I previously had BLOB in database.  I changed in database to LONGBLOB and it work!!!